# msbproj file writing documentation

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-2.0

I'm trying to debug some weirdness that's occurring within a msbproj file we have to automate our build process; I can't find a shred of documentation on writing msbproj files anywhere however, where's the "go-to" resource for msbproj writing?

EDIT: The oddity was being caused by differences in the output folder of debug and release builds- but I'm still interested in finding the answer to this question.

Comment: msbproj file extension? Is that just msbuild by another name?

Comment: Then its just msbuild. See the MSDN reference as your start:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just msbuild by another name.
 See the MSDN reference as your start:[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx)